# Performance of converting polygons to voxels and vice versa

Tags: polygon, mesh, voxel, openvdb

What is the performance of transforming between geometry primitives of **polygons** and **voxels** by [VoxelizePolygons](https://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/classopenvdb_1_1v6__2_1_1tools_1_1mesh__to__volume__internal_1_1VoxelizePolygons.html)?

Is there any benchmark tests on it? I'm trying to estimate if it is a critical overhead for an application handling polygon meshes of around several hundred mega bytes in average size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research shows:

- Using OpenVDB for voxel/mesh conversion has a time (processor) and space (memory) overhead
- If done with Metal API (GPU) it can be done much faster with less memory consumption
- Overhead of voxel/polygon conversion is annoying enough for some developers to switch to a custom voxel engine which uses Apple’s Metal API